# Save camera image to dynamic file name in Node-Red

Tags: node-red, usb-camera

I have a usb cam that take a picture from a node. But I want every image taken saved in different filename so that I can use all of images saved (not overwritten).

So my question is, how to make the file named from a function node that give an message.payload. I try use {{{msg.payload}}} but it doens't work. It just give a filename "{{{msg.payload}}}" instead of content in payload.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only nodes that specifically support mustache syntanx can use the `{{}}`, for most nodes the convention is to leave the config blank and pass it into with a specific property on the input message. In this case the documentation explains which properties to set:

> You could override with **msg.filename** the filename, with
>   **msg.filepath** the filepath and **msg.fileformat** with the fileformat.

Taken from the info sidebar for the `usbcamera` node

This means you need to set the `msg.filename` in the input message to the node and leave the filename in the config window empty.